# node.js script with synchronous sqlite3 call

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

i'm trying to use sqlite3 in node.js script, i'm using this library:

https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3

but i want that the call at the database is synchronous and not asynchronous, this is an example of the code i use:

```
var tests = [];

db.serialize(function() {

  db.each("SELECT lot_id, status FROM TestTable ORDER BY lot_id ASC", function(err, row) {
      tests.push(row.status);
      console.log("Read "+row.lot_id+" state: "+row.status);
  });
});

db.close();

for (i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
//Do something
}
```

when the execution arrives at the for loop, go over because the tests array is still empty, how i can perform this instruction sequentially?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute the for-loop in the complete callback

```
var tests = [];

db.serialize(function() {

  db.each("SELECT lot_id, status FROM TestTable ORDER BY lot_id ASC", function(err, row) {
      tests.push(row.status);
      console.log("Read "+row.lot_id+" state: "+row.status);
  }, function() { // this callback is executed when the query completed
     for (i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
     // Do something
     }
  });
});

db.close();
```

Comment: i have a very lot of code to execute after the for-loop, i can insert all this code in the serialize? there isn't a better solution?

Comment: You can put this code in a function and call that function from the complete callback.

Comment: Worked for me !!! I could not find any documentation from the npm sqlite3 wiki and this helped me!!!